# Linux Mint Wireless Driver Issue

Tags: wifi

Selecting the wireless network is ineffective as clicking apply results in it being deselected in favor of the other option, "do no use this device." [image]
How Can I install the appropriate wireless drivers?

Comment: Install dkms and your linux headers

Comment: @Francesc dkms is already installed if this is what you mean: https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/dkms How can I install "linux headers"?

Comment: yeah that's what i meant, you're going to need to plug in an ethernet cable for this, order to download your linux-headers and the command to install it is 

`apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` and then open software manager  and search for broadcom and install broadcom-sta and  broadcom-commom. Do a little bit of research on google this question has been answered before.

Comment: @Francesc I searched software manager for "broadcom" which yielded 3 results: broadcom-sta-common, broadcom-sta-dkms, and broadcom-sta-source. I would install them, but despite using ethernet to post this the software manager is not able to access the Internet.  On a different thread I tried: https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/796 where I learned to run a terminal command that revealed my PCI-ID is [14e4:4727], which is unsupported according to: http://www.linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43/#supported

Answer (score 1):

The `wl` module is unsigned , you should disable the **secure boot** from your BIOS settings , then install the `bcmwl-kernel-source`  :

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe -r b43 ssb wl brcmfmac brcmsmac bcma
sudo modprobe wl
```

Comment: So I found the boot order in the BIOS but I can't find secure boot to disable it. I went ahead and ran the first line of your script - it comes back "Media change: please insert the disk labeled 'Linux Mint 16 _petra_ - Release i38620131218 in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press enter"    This is a problem as I only have a thumbdrive.

Comment: I googled everything I could find on sources.list and tried several of them unsucessfully. How do I open my sources.list? Please pardon my ignorance.

Comment: deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 16 _petra_ - Release i386 20131218]/ saucy contrib main non-free

Comment: I restarted my computer and entered bios: BIOS Version: F.0A, Bios Vendor: Insyde, at the top it said, "Insyde H2O Setup Utility Rev 3.7

Comment: I don't know how this is, but that image isn't what is displayed in my BIOS. There are only two options in the security tab and both are password related. The computer was originally Windows 7, so it may not have secure boot.